# Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, derivatives

Determine the derivative of the following functions and state where they are analytic.

$$f(z) = \log(z^3) \quad \Rightarrow f'(z) = \frac{3z^2}{z^3} = \frac{3}{z}$$
Hence, this function is analytic everywhere except at $z=0$.

$$g(z) = \log(z^2+4i) \quad \Rightarrow g'(z) = \frac{2z}{z^2+4i}$$
So this function is analytic everywhere except $z=\pm 2i$.

$$h(z) = \log(z^4+4i) \quad \Rightarrow h'(z) = \frac{4z^3}{z^4+4i}$$
So the function is analytic everwhere except $z \in \{\text{four fourth roots of }-4i\}$ (I can use De'Moivres formula to get these).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a little error in your domains: By taking the derivative of a function, you cannot increase the domain. This effects, for example
$$D_{f'} = D_f \setminus \{z=0\} = \mathbb C \setminus \{z : z^3 \in (-\infty, 0]\} = \mathbb C \setminus (-\infty, 0]$$
With that exception (also for the other functions), your computations are correct.

---

$$g'(z) = \frac{2z}{z^2 + 4i}$$ (you forgot the "$i$")

Comment: When I stated where the functions aren't analytic, is that correct?

Comment: Not completely as I wrote above. Let
$$Z_f$$ be the set where the denominator of the derivative $f'$ disappears ($Z_g := \{z\in\mathbb C : z^2 + 4i = 0\}$, for example). Then
$$D_{f'} = D_f \setminus Z_f$$
You gave $\mathbb C \setminus Z_f$ as an answer, so all you need to do now is compute $D_f$ for your functions, i.e. the domain where your original functions are analytic.

Comment: Okay, i thought I was saying "except" meaning analytic everywhere but where I found the denominator of the derivative to be 0.

Comment: The problem is $f'$, for example, is only analytic on
$$\mathbb C \setminus (-\infty, 0]$$
although it can be _extended_ to an analytic function on
$$\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$$
You have to deal with "old debts" from the original $f$ as well, so you lose a little more than just the zeros of the denominator.